# How to achieve a solid glass/emission material with certain refraction and color

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials

I'm having trouble recreating this material in cycles:

[image]

[image]

It's a solid glass bulb with a LED inside and copper threaded fabric which gives it a copper colored glow.

I'm not sure how to achieve a similar hue / glow and IOR.

Any pointers into the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

**Blendfile:**

[image]

Comment: More reference images avaiable on:
http://bocci.ca/84-series/

Answer (score 3):

One way to achieve it is what you already have setup, just mix a *Glossy* with an *Emission Node* and fake the effect perfectly. I could optionally ditch the *Glass* node if you don't need the transparency and want to simplify the setup.

If you want a more accurate and real material at the expense of more noise and don't mind the extra render time, then you can do it with actual translucency.

Mix a *Glass* and *Translucent* node and add an actual light source inside the map. This light source may be anything from an emission surface to an actual lamp.

[image]

You may also want to re-unwrap to improve you lamp UVMap so the texture is better distributed over the surface.