# Emmisive Shading

Tags: mesh, lighting

Is there a way to have an object with an emmisive shader to still have proper shading on it?  I added an emmisive shader to a model and lost all depth with it.

Not Quite What I was looking for. I want the look to be that of this:[image: Genji Dragon] On this image, the dragon glows and is still heavily defined and can be seen in detail. ALSO I am aware this image was done in Maya.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to achieve a solid glass/emission material with certain refraction and color](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79781/how-to-achieve-a-solid-glass-emission-material-with-certain-refraction-and-color)

Comment: Also related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58272/making-an-emission-shader-emit-a-different-colour-of-light-than-the-colour-assig and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53359/how-do-you-make-an-image-emission-without-washing-out-the-image

Comment: Just mix the emission shader with whatever other shader you want it to look like

Comment: [Make the flame of a candle more yellow](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/43248/2217)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a layer weight node can give interesting results.
[image: render view]

This is the node setup :
[image: nodes]
Playing with the layer weight node blend setting will change the overall mix and the color ramps allow fine tuning of the colors and emission strength. The multiply value controls how much white your borders will be.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use this solution for your purpose. [image]

Comment: Reminds me of the webpack logo

Comment: Haha yes, I'm seeing it from my first time. Blender make us so creative ! :) https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.280984091.0312/flat,800x800,075,t.jpg